# Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported

Tags: android, ubuntu, path, raspberry-pi, environment-variables

I'm running tests from a raspberry pi 4 running [Ubuntu server 20.04](https://ubuntu.com/download/raspberry-pi) that require adb (android sdk tools). The tests have been running without issue for months now.
Yesterday the tests began to fail with the following error:

```
remote stacktrace: UnknownError: An unknown server-side error occurred while processing the command. Original error: Neither ANDROID_HOME nor ANDROID_SDK_ROOT environment variable was exported.
```

To install android-sdk i'm running the follow command: This command has been succesfully installing android-sdk with tools and setting the path and variables automatically.

```
sudo apt -y install android-sdk
```

After I started seeing the error yesterday, I attempted to set the path manually in ubuntu terminal using the following commands. (which I shouldn't have to do this, but I tried anyway to see if it would fix the issue.) It did not..

```
export ANDROID_HOME="/usr/lib/android-sdk/"
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/tools
export PATH=$PATH:$ANDROID_HOME/platform-tools
```

It is odd to me that this started to break yesterday. It had been working fine for months. Anyone else experiencing this? Any ideas on fixes?

EDIT:

I thought it might be useful to add my java installation and configuration:
I run this before installing android-sdk:

```
sudo apt-get -y update
sudo apt-get -y install openjdk-8-jdk
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-arm64
export PATH=$PATH:$JAVA_HOME/bin
```

Answer (score 2):

This error comes when you need to configuration

1. click on the "Edit configuration"
2. and add the android_home and java_home values
3. now you're good to go

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0x0EC.jpg)

Comment: How is it related to Appium configuration? The OP does not mention Appium.

Answer (score 1):

Rebooting my PC resolved the issue for me. The error message disappeared

Answer (score 0):

1. Click on my computer, right click and select properties
2. Select advanced system properties
3. Click Environment Variables
4. Add content as shown in the screenshot:
   [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/XSYvN.png)

Comment: 5.must  add  JAVA_HOME

Comment: The OP mentions Ubuntu 20.04, not Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Struggles a lot to fix this on my mac. Tried everything that's available on the web, but nothing worked.

> `Solution which worked for me --> Reinstalled Android studio.`